# How to calculate rms current from impedance and voltage?

Tags: rms

If a circuit has these values Vac  = 20Sin 130πt,  L = 32.6 mH. Do I have to get Xl first and V/Xl gives the rms current value?

Comment: 20V is MAX, so how would you get RMS?

Comment: Multiple by . 707?

Comment: Yes, so now you can calculate I.  Just realize the type of voltage you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply

$$ I_{rms} = \dfrac{|V_{rms}|}{|Z|} $$

Where \$ Z \$ is the total impedance, in this case just \$ X_L \$.  Note if there were a series \$ R \$ then \$ |Z| = \sqrt{R^2 + X_L^2} \$.

Now for a \$ \sin \$ wave you should know the relationship between peak and rms values. You should also know the relationship for \$ X_L \$ given inductance value and frequency.

I will leave the rest as an exercise.  This assumes you only want the amplitude of the rms current.

Comment: Xl = v/i or Xl = 2piefl,

Comment: Correct. \$ X_L = 2 \pi f L \$.  It's worth learning MathJax if you are going to keep using this site to write math as it looks in a text book.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when we know that:

$$\text{V}_{\space\text{L}}\left(t\right)=20\sin\left(130\pi t\right)=20\cos\left(130\pi t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\tag1$$

The 'complex' way to write this, is:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{L}}=20\exp\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\text{j}\right)\tag2$$

Now, the impedance of the coil is given by:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{L}}=\text{j}\omega\text{L}=130\pi\cdot32.6\cdot10^{-3}\cdot\text{j}\tag3$$

And so the max current value is given by:

$$\text{I}_{\text{L}|\text{max}}=\left|\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{L}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{L}}}\right|=\frac{\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{L}}\right|}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{L}}\right|}=\frac{\left|20\exp\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\text{j}\right)\right|}{\left|130\pi\cdot32.6\cdot10^{-3}\cdot\text{j}\right|}=$$
$$\frac{20}{130\pi\cdot32.6\cdot10^{-3}}=\frac{10000}{2119\pi}\approx1.50217\space\text{A}\tag4$$

And the RMS value of the current is given by:

$$\text{I}_{\text{L}|\text{rms}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{L}|\text{max}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{10000}{2119\pi}=\frac{5000\sqrt{2}}{2119\pi}\approx1.06219\space\text{A}\tag5$$

Comment: Generally you should try to avoid giving answers to the problem. By all means show the math and explain how to use it, but it's better to let the OP do the actual calculations, to help ensure they understand it.

Comment: Please don't hand over answers to questions that are obviously homework. The site will be flooded with homework problems.